# requests works over https but gets blocked over http due to cors?

Tags: laravel, apache, http, https, cors

i have a backend server with some apis written in laravel
when i try to make a request over https it works fine
but when i make the same request over http it gets blocked by cors 
saying Access-Control-Origin not present
is this normal behavior or theres something wrong with server's configuration?

p.s. the server is running apache

Comment: I think both the API and the frontend should be either on https or http. Mixing them will result in CORS errors.

Comment: im using the api through an ionic app client

Comment: Does the ionic app run on https? Does it make requests to your API via https?

Comment: if it makes the request on https it works but i want to make the request over http which doesnt work cuz i dont want to update the application version in app stores

Answer (score 0):

**Add this code at the top of api.php routes file:**

Note: This is a short term solution:

```
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin:  *');
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods:  POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers:  Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, Origin, Authorization');
  use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

Comment: thanks for answering but unfortunately this doesn't work i already use frutcake/laravel-cors for cors requests and it works over https but http requests are blocked